# Image insert width for Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I am making birthday banners for a company email to be sent out to the birthday individual. I want to know how wide these images can be for them to be banners and still fall in the size constraints of the email. Is 1000px fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you embed the image, most mailing clients will adapt the images to their own width ahead.
If it was just for computes, i would say: "Go for the 720px!" because its a standart, and even old screens will support it.
But because of the fact that there is a mobile app for web, you have 2 choices:
1 - to make a big image, but also big text so the users will see it clearly both on the computer and on the mobile.
2 - to make 2 images, 1 for mobile and 1 for web, but that requires some php and a server in the background deciding what image to show at what time..

Comment: Aim is really more aesthetic than functional. 1000px spans the width nicely on desktop BUT I like following standards so then 720px should do it?

Comment: Yea, 720 is the indastrial standarts for banners, but if you know that all of the desktops your sending to is 1920*1080 resolution (or higher), 1000 will be also great. (720 is the standart because of alot of screens procuced in the 90's that were 1600*1000O